# How to link my external css in sharepoint - it's hosted in my server and is it possible to link CDN bootstrap CSS?

Tags: cdn

How to link my external css in sharepoint - it's hosted in my server  and is it possible to link CDN bootstrap CSS?

Comment: Can you please elaborate where would you like to use css (both external and CDN)? In content editor web part or in master page?

Comment: there is a one table, I was trying add style in Embed code,  but when I save this changes my style are not showing

Comment: I am new to this sharepoint style, so whated to know  only inline CSS work here, or we can add internal CSS like <style> </style> in same page and is it possble to add external css,

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Designer 2013 and open your site from it. Now navigate to masterpage folder and paste your external style sheet there(in mine i have a css folder created). Open your page layout and type this:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&#60;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/css/YOUREXTERNALSTYLESHEET.css %&#62;" runat="server" after="corev15.css">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:CssRegistration>-->
```

Note the above line has to go immediately above the `<!--MS:<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">-->`
 tag.

Save and open it. After applying a page to the page layout, you will be good to go.

Steps to add the page and apply it to a page layout:

1. Click on the Settings cog/gear icon and click on add a page.
2. Name you page and click create.
3. Click on Page tab from the ribbon and click on page layout, choose the page 
   layout you had style sheet in and you are good.